# Does "The Whalebone Parrot" draw inspiration from any specific Apache sources?

Tags: short-stories, inspiration, darcie-little-badger

"The Whalebone Parrot" is a short horror story by Darcie Little Badger. In it, a parrot is killed, and then possesses Loretta to try to kill the cat that killed the parrot.

Darcie Little Badger often draws from Apache traditions and beliefs to form her stories - e.g., Owl in" Owl vs. the Neighborhood Watch", or the theme of the windigo in "The Famine King".

Does this story draw from any similar sources?

Comment: Strongly related: [How is the possession by “The Whalebone Parrot” related to Loretta's Native American identity?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8907/17) I suspect an answer to one would also resolve t'other.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I don't know if that's necessarily the case. I think the answers could still be largely orthognal.